How come an upgraded ASP.net Core 6.0 to 8.0 App isnt automatically able to use the User Secrets Configuration Provider?
I have upgraded my ASP.NET Core app from version 6.0 to 8.0.  I have upgraded all the nuget packages.
I have a Secrets.json file in Connected Services in VS 2022.  I have the "ConnectionStrings.AppConfig" value in it.
When I start the application it doesn't use the user secrets.
However, when I add "builder.Configuration.AddUserSecrets();" to my Program.cs it works.  I shouldn't have to do this.
When I create a brand new ASP.NET Core app everything works fine without me having to put in that line.
What do I need to do to make it work without adding that line of code?

Post your code. We can't guess which builder is used. Are you using the legacy WebHost? Or the new WebApplicationBuilder? The templates use WebApplicationBuilder

@PanagiotisKanavos var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

Post your code in the question itself. User Secrets stores a UserSecretsId in the project file. Does your csproj file include a <UserSecretsId> element? Does the secrets file exist in the expected location, %APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<user_secrets_id>\secrets.json ?

Yes my Secrets.json has :{
"ConnectionStrings:AppConfig": "Endpoint=https://app-configuration-services.azconfig.io;Id=2Ddn;Secret=FLjaFZGx7Uw3kS1hWAgfHmBjqWRqsidi3PR5vQJjf7C0nup6LDEZJQQJ99AGACYeBjFMzAcUAAABAZACRjU8"
}
My project file has:     8fd96a16-931a-4460-ab39-b58c8acc992e

I created a new ASP.NET Core app on .net 6.0 and upgraded it to 8.0 and everything works as expected, meaning Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig") returns the connection string. Can you please provide your whole Program.cs logic?

@MxNbrt Everything doesn't work.  Everything except the User Secrets ConfigurationProvider.
The code is:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.AddUserSecrets();
var appCongifConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");
builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration(appCongifConnectionString);
builder.Services.AddAzureAppConfiguration();
builder.Services.Configure(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppName"));
The above works.  But if I remove the AddUserSecrets() it doesn't

Add the code to the question itself, not comments. This is unreadable

When EnvironmentName is Development, the initialized WebApplicationBuilder  provides default configuration and calls AddUserSecrets. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=windows#register-the-user-secrets-configuration-source
You can check whether your environment is configured as Development by setting it in the launchSettings.json file .

@MikeLenart Please move all the code/config from your comments in to the question. It's unreadable where it is and not easily discovered by (new) people viewing the question.

Can you please run these checks to verify:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var env = builder.Environment;
if (!env.IsDevelopment())
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Not development env");
}
if (env.ApplicationName.Length == 0)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("ApplicationName not set");
}

var secretsPath = PathHelper.GetSecretsPathFromSecretsId("8fd96a16-931a-4460-ab39-b58c8acc992e");
if (!File.Exists(secretsPath))
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("secrets.json does not exist");
}

var configSource = builder.Configuration.Sources.OfType<JsonConfigurationSource>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Path == "secrets.json");
if (configSource is null)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("No secrets.json in config");
}

var appCongifConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appCongifConnectionString))
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("appCongifConnectionString is empty");
}

Which exception is thrown?

Yes that was great set of code.  It was the it was the Azure environment and not Development.  Thank you!.
